# Docker device-cgroups-rule, mknod and mount

Tags: docker

I'm attempting to implement what is described here:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/#dealing-with-dynamically-created-devices---device-cgroup-rule

Similar to the page I am creating (and then starting) a container as follows:

```
docker create --device-cgroup-rule='b 8:* rmw' -name my-container my-image
```

Quoting from the above page

> Then, a user could ask udev to execute a script that would docker exec
> my-container mknod newDevX c 42  the required device when it is
> added.

Within the container (docker exec -it my-container sh) I then mknod a device:

```
mknod /dev/sdc1 b 8 33
```

The device was reported as above by lsblk:

```
sdc           8:32   1 500M  0 disk 
└─sdc1        8:33   1 500M  0 part
```

mknod succeeds but mounting /dev/sdc1 gives an error:

```
$ mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt
mount: /mnt: permission denied.
```

I also tried various other things like

- mknod with -m
- docker start with --cap-add=CAP_MKNOD

EDIT:
I also tried starting with --privileged but without the /dev/sdc1 precreated and it worked. It must have something to do with Capabilities or other differences between privileged and non-privileged mode. I tried with --cap-add=CAP_MKNOD and CAP_SYS_ADMIN but it now reports a difference message:

```
$ mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt
mount: /mnt: cannot mount /dev/sdc1 read-only.
```

Comment: did you find any solution for this problem? I have the same... and I would be happy to have a hint :)

Comment: Can't remember exactly but I think we went with privileged mode.

Comment: Could you please check the default permissions on the device in question inside the container?

`docker exec CONTAINER_ID ls -lh /dev/sdc1`

Correct `mknod -m` mode should do the trick. Bare in mind that you may need `execute` bit as well.